# Combining input-append input-prepend add-on and spanX classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a small project and decided to use Twitter Bootstrap as I am not very good at design !

Well I am facing a problem with the `input-append` and `input-prepend` elements when I try to combine them with `.spanX` classes to have them the same size.

Currently here is the problem

When I do this :

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 input-append input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">
            <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="span8 uneditable-input text-right">0</span>
        <span class="add-on">
            <i class="icon-tint"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

everything is fine

If I add a `spanX` to the prepended element it works perfectly.

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 input-append input-prepend">
        <span class="span2 add-on">
            <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="span8 uneditable-input text-right">0</span>
        <span class="add-on">
            <i class="icon-tint"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But then, if I try to put a `spanX` element to the appended element it doesn't work anymore and the layout is broken

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 input-append input-prepend">
        <span class="span2 add-on">
            <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="span8 uneditable-input text-right">0</span>
        <span class="span2 add-on">
            <i class="icon-tint"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So does anyone already had the same issue ? I looked in the site but didn't find anything relevant to this problem.

I know sometimes the fact that `span` elements are not inline in the code are causing problems but I didn't experience that and even if everything is inline the problem persists.

Thanks for reading. Any help or advice welcome =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `span*` classes come with a `float:left;` declaration - that is what is causing your problem.  You might be better to create a class and define the width as you'd like.  Then you will not get the troublesome float that comes with using a span class.

Your example updated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dusthaines/77XEk/3/

Comment: I understand what you say, but if all elements have a `span*` class, then they are all floating and should be following the order of declaration in the DOM, shouldn't they ? I will follow your example and let you know. Thanks a lot

Comment: As I suspected it is not working. First, I am not sure you can give a width to a `<span>` element without making it floating or block (even `display` CSS property set to `inline-block` doesn't work. Right ?

Comment: Finally your input helped a lot ! I appears that it is the `uneditable-input.span*` element that loses its `float: left;` property. So as You suggested, I just had to create a custom class to give it back its `float: left;` property ! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: hi yezahel, great observations. i totally overlooked the fact that they should have floated in order and there should have been no problem to start with.  great find regarding the "uneditable-input.span*" element.  it might be worth it to report this to the project as a bug.  i'll take a look and see if it's been mentioned yet.